# Exclude SSH and Webserver from OpenVPN connection

Tags: ssh, openvpn, webserver

I have a server hosted outside that has a webserver and I access it using SSH, its ip is `111.111.111.111`. The problem arise when I connect the server to a VPN using OpenVPN `sudo openvpn XXX.ovpn`(configuration file is taken from NordVPN) then SSH and Webserver stop to work, I want to access the server using the same ip `111.111.111.111`.

I still manage to access it by adding my routing to my PC `ip route add <MY_IP_PC> via 10.0.0.1 dev enp0s6` but I'm the only one that can reach the webserver in this way, everyone else cannot.

**Before VPN Connection**

```
ubuntu@server1:~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:00:17:00:78:88 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.67/24 metric 100 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global enp0s6
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::17ff:fe00:7888/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
ubuntu@server1:~$ ip route
default via 10.0.0.1 dev enp0s6
default via 10.0.0.1 dev enp0s6 proto dhcp src 10.0.0.67 metric 100
10.0.0.0/24 dev enp0s6 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.67 metric 100
10.0.0.1 dev enp0s6 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.0.67 metric 100
<MY_IP_PC> via 10.0.0.1 dev enp0s6
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s6 scope link
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s6 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.0.67 metric 100
169.254.169.254 via 10.0.0.1 dev enp0s6 proto dhcp src 10.0.0.67 metric 100
```

**After VPN Connection**

```
ubuntu@server1:~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:00:17:00:78:88 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.67/24 metric 100 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global enp0s6
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::17ff:fe00:7888/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none
    inet 10.8.1.10/24 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::4f41:a589:8792:84e6/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
ubuntu@server1:~$ ip route
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.1.1 dev tun0
default via 10.0.0.1 dev enp0s6
default via 10.0.0.1 dev enp0s6 proto dhcp src 10.0.0.67 metric 100
10.0.0.0/24 dev enp0s6 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.67 metric 100
10.0.0.1 dev enp0s6 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.0.67 metric 100
10.8.1.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.1.10
<MY_IP_PC> via 10.0.0.1 dev enp0s6
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.1.1 dev tun0
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s6 scope link
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s6 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.0.67 metric 100
169.254.169.254 via 10.0.0.1 dev enp0s6 proto dhcp src 10.0.0.67 metric 100
217.138.219.171 via 10.0.0.1 dev enp0s6
```

Comment: What's the purpose of running the openvpn client on the server?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ip route
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.1.1 dev tun0
```

So, half your traffic (0.0.0.0/1, i.e. if the destination IP address ends with an even number) is going through the VPN connection and the other half (if the destination IP address ends with an odd number) is going through your default gateway. This makes little sense to say the least.

In other words, the replies to HTTP and SSH connections are likely to go through the VPN, although the request came from the enp0s6 interface. A decent firewall on the VPN side would probably drop them.